# How to make clock applet show "fuzzy" time?

Tags: gnome-panel, clock

How to make the gnome panel clock show time in "fuzzy" format? E.g. "It's morning".
I think it was present in KDE in the good ole times. Not sure about now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a separate fuzzy-clock applet by Troy Rennie

Just two little problems I've noticed:
Nothing happens if you click on it, and it looks just *very slightly* wrong on ubuntu 10.10.

But other than that, it's fine.

http://code.google.com/p/fuzzy-clock/

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the panel and go to Add Widgets.  Go to the Date & Time section, and there is a Fuzzy Clock widget available.  Add that to your panel, then right click on the old clock to find the option to remove the non-fuzzy one.

Comment: from the tags it looks like he meant in GNOME, but who knows.

Comment: Oh, the "it was in kde 3" made me assume KDE user

Comment: yeap, I wrote “gnome” and I meant “gnome”